# c++ isalpha lookup table

Tags: c++, char, lookup-tables

Whats the easiest way to implement a lookup table that checks to see if a character is an alpha or not using a lookup table with an array 256  chars (256 bytes)?  I know I can use isalpha function, but a lookup table can supposedly be more efficient, requiring one comparison instead of multiple ones.  I was thinking of corresponding the index with the char decimal conversion and checking directly if it the char was equivalent to that.

Comment: If a lookup table is more efficient, you can expect your system to already be using one. If you care enough, you can use the system service to initialise your own lookup table, then benchmark both.  If your lookup table does somehow prove more performant, then that bootstrapping approach is so fast that as a one-off initialisation it remains practical.

Comment: There is one more thing you can do to make a lookup table fast.  You can make sure the compiler locates the lookup table in the same segment as code that uses it.  in msvc, I use #pragma section and #pragma alloc_text to do this.  Of course if your code that hits the lookup table is inlined, then this won't work so well.

Comment: @Tony D.  The system takes into account locale and so the system isalpha is pretty slow compared to other methods.

Comment: unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A' is almost as fast as the table lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the first rule of optimisation: don't do it.

Then remember the second rule of optimisation, to be applied very rarely: don't do it yet.

Then, if you really are encountering a bottleneck and you've identified `isalpha` as the cause, then something like this *might* be faster, depending on how your library implements the function. You'll need to measure the performance in your environment, and only use it if there really is a measurable improvement. This assumes you don't need to test values outside the range of `unsigned char` (typically 0...255); you'll need a bit of extra work for that.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>

class IsAlpha
{
public:
    IsAlpha()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; ++i)
            table[i] = std::isalpha(i);
    }

    bool operator()(unsigned char i) const {return table[i];}

private:
    bool table[UCHAR_MAX+1];
};
```

Usage:

```
IsAlpha isalpha;

for (int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; ++i)
    assert(isalpha(i) == bool(std::isalpha(i)));
```

Answer (score 4):

I've always used this single compare method (i assume it pipelines better), since its faster than doing up to four compares.

```
unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A'
```

I benchmarked a few different ways and took into account TLB cache miss for lookup table method.  I ran the benchmarks on windows.  Here are the times if the charset was '0'..'z':

```
lookup tbl no tlb miss:                        4.8265 ms
lookup table with tlb miss:                    7.0217 ms
unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A':  10.5075 ms
(ch>='A' && ch<='Z') || (ch>='a' && ch<='z'): 17.2290 ms
isalpha:                                      28.0504 ms
```

You can clearly see that the locale code has a cost.

Here are the times if the charset was 0..255:

```
tbl no tlb miss:                               12.6833 ms
unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A':   29.2403 ms
(ch>='A' && ch<='Z') || (ch>='a' && ch<='z'):  34.8818 ms
isalpha:                                       78.0317 ms
tbl with tlb miss:                            143.7135 ms
```

The times are longer because more chars were tested.  The # of segments I used for the tlb "flush" was larger in the second test.  It might be that the table lookup method suffers more from the tlb miss than the first run indicates.  You can also see that the single cmp method works better when the character is an alpha.

The lookup table method is the best if comparing many characters in a row, but it is not that much better than the single cmp method.  If you are comparing characters here and there, then the tlb cache miss might make the tbl method worse than the single cmp method.  The single cmp method works best when the characters are more likely to be alphas.

Here is the code:

```
__forceinline bool isalpha2(BYTE ch) {
    return (ch>='A' && ch<='Z') || (ch>='a' && ch<='z');
}

__forceinline bool isalpha1(BYTE ch) {
    return unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A';
}
bool* aTbl[256];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    __int64 n = 0, cTries = 100000;
    int b=63;
    int ch0=' ', ch1 ='z'+1;
    ch0=0, ch1 = 256;
    // having 255 tables instead of one lets us "flush" the tlb.
    // Intel tlb should have about ~32 entries (depending on model!) in it, 
    // so using more than 32 tables should have a noticable effect.
    for (int i1=0 ; i1<256 ; ++i1) {
        aTbl[i1] = (bool*)malloc(16384);
        for (int i=0 ; i<256 ; ++i)
            aTbl[i1][i] = isalpha(i);
    }

    { CBench Bench("tbl with tlb miss");
        for (int i=1 ; i<cTries ; ++i) {
            for (int ch = ch0 ; ch < ch1 ; ++ ch) 
                n += aTbl[ch][ch];  // tlb buster
        }
    }
    { CBench Bench("tbl no tlb miss");
        for (int i=1 ; i<cTries ; ++i) {
            for (int ch = ch0 ; ch < ch1 ; ++ ch) 
                n += aTbl[0][ch];
        }
    }
    { CBench Bench("isalpha");
        for (int i=1 ; i<cTries ; ++i) {
            for (int ch = ch0 ; ch < ch1 ; ++ ch)
                n += isalpha(ch);
        }
    }
    { CBench Bench("unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A'");
        for (int i=1 ; i<cTries ; ++i) {
            for (int ch = ch0 ; ch < ch1 ; ++ ch)
                n += isalpha1(ch);
        }
    }
    { CBench Bench("(ch>='A' && ch<='Z') || (ch>='a' && ch<='z')");
        for (int i=1 ; i<cTries ; ++i) {
            for (int ch = ch0 ; ch < ch1 ; ++ ch) 
                n += isalpha2(ch);
        }
    }
    return n;
}


class  CBench {
public:
    __declspec(noinline) CBench(CBench* p) : m_fAccumulate(false), m_nTicks(0),
     m_cCalls(0), m_pBench(p), m_desc(NULL), m_nStart(GetBenchMark()) { }
    __declspec(noinline) CBench(const char *desc_in, bool fAccumulate=false) : 
     m_fAccumulate(fAccumulate), m_nTicks(0), m_cCalls(0), m_pBench(NULL), 
     m_desc(desc_in), m_nStart(GetBenchMark()) {    }
    __declspec(noinline) ~CBench() {
        __int64 n = (m_fAccumulate) ? m_nTicks : GetBenchMark() - m_nStart;
        if (m_pBench) {
            m_pBench->m_nTicks += n;
            m_pBench->m_cCalls++;
            return;
        } else if (!m_fAccumulate) {
            m_cCalls++;
        }
        __int64 nFreq;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&nFreq);
        double ms = ((double)n * 1000)/nFreq;
        printf("%s took: %.4f ms, calls: %d, avg:%f\n", m_desc, ms, m_cCalls,
             ms/m_cCalls);
    }
    __declspec(noinline) __int64 GetBenchMark(void) {
        __int64 nBenchMark;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&nBenchMark);
        return nBenchMark;
    }
    LPCSTR     m_desc;
    __int64    m_nStart, m_nTicks;
    DWORD      m_cCalls;
    bool       m_fAccumulate;
    CBench*    m_pBench;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, according to Plauger in "The Standard C Library" [91] `isalpha` is oftentimes implemented using a lookup table. That book is really dated but this might still be the case today. Here's his proposed definition for isalpha

**Function**

```
int isalpha(int c)
{
    return (_Ctype[c] & (_LO|_UP|_XA));
}
```

**Macro**

```
#define isalpha(c) (_Ctype[(int)(c)] & (_LO|_UP|_XA))
```

Comment: It is still the case.  Even in the C++ locale system: see the specialization for char of the ctype facet.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler library's implementation is likely to be quite efficient and is probably already using a lookup table for most cases, but also handling some situations that might be a little tricky to get right if you're going to do your own `isalpha()`:

- dealing with signed characters correctly (using negative indexing on the lookup table)
- dealing with non-ASCII locales

You might not need to handle non-ASCII locales, in which case you might (maybe) be able to improve slightly over the library.

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if a macro or function that simply returned the result of:

```
((('a' <= (c)) && ((c) <= 'z')) || (('A' <= (c)) && ((c) <= 'Z')))
```

might be faster than a table lookup since it wouldn't have to hit memory. But I doubt it would be faster in any meaningful way, and would be difficult to measure a difference except maybe in a benchmark that did nothing but `isalpha()` calls (which might also improve the table lookup results since the table would likely be in the cache for many of the tests).

And is `isalpha()` really a bottleneck?  For anyone?

Just use the one in your compiler's library.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it was really a bottleneck for me, and caching the results in a table did give a measurable improvement. I think most of the improvement came from inlining the lookup function.

Comment: @Mike: well, I'll be.  I may have to delete my smartass remark.

Comment: @Michael: No, it's still a good remark; optimising library functions is almost never necessary.

Comment: @Mike: don't you mean optimizing *over* library functions, like in trying to do better ? I, for one, do hope that the Standard Library I used has been carefully optimized.

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, that's what I meant; something the library *users* should almost never need to do.

Comment: @Mike: I thought so, the comment looked weird otherwise :D

Comment: unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A' is almost as fast as the table lookup, and almost twice as fast as the 4 compare method.  See my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for alphabetic characters, a-Z, that's a lot less characters than your 255 array.  You can subtract 'A' from the ASCII character in question (the lowest alphabetic character), which will be the index into your array.  e.g. 'B' - 'A' is 1.  The test, if negative, is not alpha.  If greater than your max alpha ('z'), then it is not alpha.

If you are using unicode at all, this method will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement isalpha a lot more trivially than with a lookup table. Using the fact that characters 'a'-'z' and 'A'-'Z' are successive in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) a simple test like this is sufficient:

```
char c ;
// c gets some value
if(('A'<=c && 'Z'>=c) || ('a'<=c && 'z'>=c)) // c is alpha
```

Note that this doesn't take into account different locales.

Comment: Here's another reason not to bother with this kind of optimization.  Your implementation is broken (the expression always evaluates to 0). I suppose that would be fixed after testing.

Comment: And it's probably slower than a single table lookup (although that's heavily dependent on platform and circumstance).

Comment: unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A' is almost as fast as the table lookup, and almost twice as fast as the 4 compare method.  See my post.